# TLSSocket not reporting authorized and authorizationError correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to set up a `TLSSocket` connection to an Electrum server in Node. For this I want to allow self signed certificates, but I do want to notify/log when the connection uses a self signed certificate.

To allow self signed certs I am using the `rejectUnauthorized: false` option when connecting. This works as expected. However, according to the [Node TLS docs](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_authorizationerror) the connected socket should report both an `authorized` flag as well as an `authorizationError` when the authorization fails. It looks like this is not being reported correctly.

This is the bare-bones example code demonstrating my issue:

```js
const tls = require('tls');

// const host = 'bch.imaginary.cash';
const host = 'electroncash.de'
const port = 50002;

const socket = tls.connect(port, host, { rejectUnauthorized: false });

socket.on('error', console.log);

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(`Successfully connected to ${host}:${port}`);
  console.log(socket.authorized);
  console.log(socket.authorizationError);
})
```

I ran this code with two different servers: `bch.imaginary.cash` which has a CA-signed cert, and `electroncash.de` which has a self signed cert. When running this code with `rejectUnauthorized` set to `false`, both hosts result in this:

```
Successfully connected to electroncash.de:50002
false
null
```

I would expect the CA-signed connection to report `authorized` as `true` and I would expect the self signed connection to report `authorizationError` as non-null.

I also tried running the same code with `rejectUnauthorized` set to `true`, in which case the CA-signed connection succeeded (but still has `authorized` set to `false`) and the self signed connection resulted in an error:

```
Error: self signed certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1501:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:936:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:710:12) {
  code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been struggling with this issue for a while before starting to type out this question. After I wrote out the full question I figured out the answer, so I decided to still post the question and provide the answer myself.

The `'connect'` event on a `TLSSocket` is inherited from the unencrypted `net.Socket`. So in this case this is the wrong event to listen for. Instead, you should listen for the `'secureConnect'` event. When we change the event listener code in the original question to:

```js
socket.on('secureConnect', () => {
  console.log(`Successfully connected to ${host}:${port}`);
  console.log(socket.authorized);
  console.log(socket.authorizationError);
})
```

The results are exactly as expected. In other words, the CA-signed connection reports `true` and `null`, while the self signed connection reports `false` and `DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT`.